# Real Analysis - Limit Point And Supremum of the set.

Tags: real-analysis

True / False

(1) The only limit point of the set $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} : n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ is $0$

(2) The supremum of the set ${\frac{1}{10}, \frac{11}{100}, \frac{111}{1000}, \frac{1111}{10000},.....}$ is  $\frac{1}{9}$

Can somebody provide any ideas how to approach these types of questions?

Solution Attempt:

(1) True. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m}$ is $0+0 = 0$.

(2) True.

Comment: for (1) if you fix $n$ and $m\to\infty$ what happens ? for (2) just notice the sequence is increasing.

Comment: what does increasing sequence tell us?

Comment: that the sup is the limit

Comment: Any unbounded increasing sequence necessarily goes to ∞

Comment: so (2) is False since it's supremum = ∞?

Comment: The $k$th term of (2) equals $\sum_{n=1}^k 10^{-n}$.

Comment: For the first question, there are infinite number of limit points exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1:**
Answer is false.
If you fix $n=1$ then varying $m$ then we will conclude that $1$ is a limit point. And choosing different values of $n$ and arguing like this. Thus this set has infinitely many limit points. Also $0$ is a limit point.

**Note**:
${1+\frac{1}{m}}$ converges to $1$ as $m$ tend to infinity.

**Question 2:**

$0.1,0.11,0.111.... $ which is increasing and converges to $0.1111.... $=$1/9$. So sup=$1/9$.